# semi-direct product between manifolds

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, surgery-theory

question 1: Are there mathematical definition of the semi-direct product between manifolds
$$
M^{d_1} \rtimes V^{d_2}?
$$

For example, is it defined as a fibration such that $M^{d_1}$ is the fiber and the $V^{d_2}$ is the base, so the total space is a bundle with the following relation
$$
M^{d_1} \hookrightarrow M^{d_1} \rtimes V^{d_2} \to V^{d_2}
$$

question 2: Can $M^{d_1} \rtimes V^{d_2}$ be a mapping torus?

question 3: What is the mapping class group of $M^{d_1} \rtimes V^{d_2}$?

Partial answers are very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not a thing. And you will have extreme difficulty in calculating anything about mapping class groups in dimension bigger than 3.

Comment: "What" is not a thing ?.

Comment: The first question you ask is "Is there a definition of semidirect product of manifolds". The answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any standard way to define this semidirect product of manifolds, and I don't see how we can invent one.

Your intuition is correct that a fiber bundle of manifolds is like a product manifold but with more complex structure, roughly in the same way that a semidirect product of groups is like a product group but with more complex structure.

However, I think the analogy breaks down. In the case of groups, when we have $G = N \rtimes_\phi H$, we are also given an action $\phi$ of $H$ on $N$. In the case of manifolds $M$ and $V$, in order for $V$ to act on $M$, $V$ needs some algebraic structure. We could require $V$ to be a Lie group (basically, a group which is also a manifold), but I still don't see how to define the total space.

A standard mapping torus on $M$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $M$, but its base space is a circle whereas you want it to be a more general $V$.

Comment: The analogy is actually very solid: extensions $1 \to N \to G \to G/N \to 1$ of groups correspond exactly to fibrations $BN \to BG \to B(G/N)$ of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces. If $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}$ we get mapping tori. In the other direction, a fiber bundle $F \to E \to B$ of connected spaces is like an extension $\Omega F \to \Omega E \to \Omega B$ of loop spaces, and all such extensions can be thought of as arising from a generalized semidirect product coming from an action of $\Omega B$ on $\Omega F$, in a suitable sense.

Comment: thanks +1, for the help

Comment: @annieheart, you might be interested in [MSE "Question on notation (topology & fiber bundles)"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225083/question-on-notation-topology-fiber-bundles).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Example? could $U(n)$ be considered a fiber bundle with fiber $U(1)$ over base $SU(n)$ ?