# Notation on fibre bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, geometric-topology

I came up this morning with the following question and after looking for it for a while on the internet i found this old question on math.stackexchange with no answers. Could anyone please give some clue? Thanks a lot in advance 
[Question on notation (topology & fiber bundles)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225083/question-on-notation-topology-fiber-bundles)

Comment: Let $X,Y$ be a pair of spaces with continuous actions of a topological group $G$. Form the $G$-space $X\times Y$ with the diagonal action, and let $X\times_GY$ be the quotient $(X\times Y)/G$. In particular, if $X$ is a right $G$-space and $Y$ is a left $G$-space, then $X\times_GY=X\times Y/[(xg,y)\sim (x,gy)]$. The space $X\times_GY$ is often called the *Borel Construction*, or *Balance Product*.

Comment: I think that was your question.

Comment: That is so accurate. Thanks a lot, Tyrone.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225083.

Comment: It is obviously a duplicate because nobody answered to the first question. Indeed, that is what i said in the description..